# Explain this part of Arrowlets source code

Tags: javascript

I was looking through the [Arrowlets source code](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/arrowlets/releases/arrowlets-alpha-20081103.js), and found this section near the top:

```
/*
 * Box: a temporary (singleton) place to put stuff. Used as a helper for constructors with variadic arguments.
 */
function Box(content) {
    Box.single.content = content;
    return Box.single;
}
/* JavaScript hackery based on the strange semantics of "new":
 * - Box() assigns Box.single.value, so Box.single has to be defined;
 * - properties can be assigned to numbers (but have no effect);
 * - when Box.single = 1 (or any non-Object), "new Box" returns "this". */
Box.single = 1;
Box.single = new Box;
Box.prototype.toString = function Box$prototype$toString() {
    return "[Box " + this.content + "]";
}
```

I also looked through some of `Box`'s uses in the source code, and it seems like it is another way to pass multiple arguments, but I really don't understand how. Also, the comments state that:

> when Box.single = 1 (or any non-Object), "new Box" returns "this".

But I thought whenever a constructor function was called with `new`, `this` would be returned. Can someone please explain this to me?

**UPDATE**:

I'm having a hard time understanding why `Box.single` has to be set to a non-object for this approach to work and what is gained with the trickery using the `new` operator. Examples from a NodeJS repl:

**No `new` and using a non-object**

```
> function Box(content) {
... Box.single.content = content;
... return Box.single;
... }
Box.single = {}; // NOTE: Setting Box.Single to an Object
{}
> //NOTE: Not using the "new" operator at all
undefined
> Box(23)
{ content: 23 }
> Box.single
{ content: 23 }
> Box({'name': 'John'})
{ content: { name: 'John' } }
> Box.single
{ content: { name: 'John' } }
```

**Using `new` and an object**

```
> function Box(content) {
... Box.single.content = content;
... return Box.single;
... }
undefined
> Box.single = {}; // Setting Box.single to an object
{}
> Box.single = new Box; // Using the new operator
{ content: undefined }
> Box({'name': 'John'})
{ content: { name: 'John' } }
> Box.single
{ content: { name: 'John' } }
```

as opposed to using the method from **Arrowlets**:

```
> function Box(content) {
... Box.single.content = content;
... return Box.single;
... }
undefined
> Box.single = 1; // Setting Box.single to a Non-Object
1
> Box.single = new Box; // Using the new operator
{}
> Box(23)
{ content: 23 }
> Box({'name': 'John'})
{ content: { name: 'John' } }
> Box.single
{ content: { name: 'John' } }
```

It seems like the arrowlets approach is just a convoluted way of accomplishing something simple. What am I missing?

Comment: Some literals like strings and numbers are not really objects, so `'' != new String('')` and `0 != new Number(0)`. A string or number literal can't hold properties attached to it, while a string or number created with the constructor can. `Box.single.content` will be `undefined` with literals (`Box.single` will still be a literal), but not with constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arrowlets code never uses this function with "new", except for this one call:

```
Box.single = new Box;
```

So your comment/concern about "this" is relevant only to this one use. You can see that Box is a function, and that Box has a property called single. With the above assignment, Box.single is set to point to the instance of the Box function - the 'this' returned by new Box;

Before Box() is called as a constructor, some trickery is needed in order for the call to be successful. In that case, Box.single has been set to the value of 1, so that setting the content of single in:

```
Box.single.content = content;
```

will be harmless/ignored/however you want to think of it. "content" will be undefined with the

```
new Box;
```

call. We don't want the constructor to throw. Hence the trickery.
Upon return from the constructor call, Box.single is set to the instantiated Box()

The developer is trying to create a singleton that holds on to "content". The goal is to work with Box() in order to package an arbitrary number of arguments together. This has to do with making many-parameter JavaScript functions work with Tuples which underlie the Arrowlets implementation. Here the Box is used to create a Tuple when there are more than 2 elements in an array:

```
Tuple.fromArray = function Tuple$fromArray(array) {
    switch (array.length) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            return array[0];
        case 2:
            return new Pair(array[0], array[1]);
        default:
            return new Tuple(Box(array));
    }
}
```

When a Tuple is created with the constructor below, if a Box is passed in, the content of the box becomes the 'components' of the Tuple

```
function Tuple() {
    if (arguments[0] instanceof Box) {
        var components = arguments[0].content;
    } else {
        [...omitted stuff...]
    }
    /* properties */
    this.components = components;
    this.length = components.length;
}
```

That's all that's going on!

Comment: First, wouldn't `Box.single` become `{content: {mystuff: 2}}` instead of just `{mystuff: 2}`? I also updated my question asking for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: yep...i was leaving work and in a hurry. sorry to mislead at the end of the post. so i updated it. -b

Comment: Why would a developer want to do this kind of thing when there are other alternatives? Hey that's a whole different question! One purpose could be to differentiate the type of argument that was passed in and respond differently to it.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in `instanceof`:

```
...
Box.single = {};
Box.single = new Box; // with or without this line
Box(1) instanceof Box; // false
```

and:

```
...
Box.single = 1;
Box.single = new Box;
Box(1) instanceof Box; // true
```

In the first case, because `Box.single` is an object, the call above to `new Box` returns `Box.single` which is a plain `{}` object, according to the JavaScript rules. Every subsequent call to `new Box` or `Box` returns that same plain object.

In the second case, `Box.single` is not an object, so `new Box` returns a new `Box` object and assigns it to `Box.single`, and every subsequent call to `new Box` or `Box` returns that same `Box` object.

Note that, perhaps surprisingly, `new` does not have to return `this`; it can return any `obj` where `typeof(obj) == "object"` by calling `return obj` (if `typeof(obj) != "object"`, then `new` returns `this`). E.g.:

```
function Foo() {
    this instanceof Foo; // true
}
function Bar() {
    this instanceof Bar; // true
    return new Foo();
}
(new Bar) instanceof Bar; // false
(new Bar) instanceof Foo; // true
```

That's also why `new Box` can be used instead of just `Box`:

```
a = Box(1);
b = new Box(2);
a === b; // true
```